# Newbie, need help creating a search page and a detail page

Tags: php, mysql, hyperlink

I am doing what should be a simple task, given to me by a php tutor. I have a movie DB that has been populated with 3 movies and details about those movies. I have been manipulating this data for various other tasks and am now stuck. I need the main page to show the movie titles and have each title be clickable. Then, when clicked, you would end up at the detail page for that movie where you will see the rating, image, and description. My code is a total disaster right now and I am deleting and adding, but here it is, anyway.

```
     <html>
 <body>
 <table>

 <?php error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE); ?>

 <?php
```

**EDITED TO ADD THE FOLLOWING**

This is the functioning search page and it works.

```
<html>
```

">

```
</body>
```

I am still struggling with the details page, but should have it up soon.

```
     function getRecords($query) {
         $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "movie", "moviepw");
         if (!$con)
         {
            die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
         }

         mysql_select_db("movies", $con);

         $result = mysql_query($query);
         return $result;

}

         function buildQuery($result)

         {

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM table1";

         while($row = mysql_fetch_array($records)){

         ?>

 <a href="moviedata5.php?id= <?php echo "$movie_title" ?> <?php echo "$movie_id desc"   ?>"> </a>

 <table border='1'>
                    <thead>
                           <tr>
                                  <th><a href="?movie_id=movie_title">Title</a></th>

                           </tr>
                    </thead>

   <? } echo $sortorder = $_GET['sortorder'];
         $query = buildQuery($sortorder);
         $records = getRecords($query);

}

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($records)){ ?>
            <tr>
                   <td><?= $row['movie_rating']; ?></td>
                   <td> <img src="<?= $row['movie_image'];?>"> </td>
                   <td><?= $row['movie_description']; ?></td>
            </tr>

    <?  } ?>

    </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So what is your specific question?

Comment: @cherylannCE You aren't lying that your code is a disaster......

Comment: @LaurenceBurke Why is it a disaster? Perhaps you could help him in identifying what's wrong with it?

Comment: Well, I have neither been able to create a detail page, nor a result page. So, my question is, what do I need to do to make that happen?

Comment: I've posted my WIP so that you can see what I've been trying so far.

Comment: @george its a disaster in the fact that the flow is all disrupted by using functions when it should be written as inline code so its very very hard to follow.... good description?

Comment: @LaurenceBurke, so, can you help me fix it then? I've read through tons of tutorials and can't find what I need. Even just a link to a good tutorial would help me.

Comment: @CherylAnnCE what is your movie table structure... i.e. Column names and datatypes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `buildQuery()` function is trying to fetch result rows from `$records, which has not been defined in that function. So you're trying to do a`mysql_fetch_array(NULL)`, basically, which will fail.

Answer (score 0):

Ask your PHP Tutor for help on solving this problem.